# XML Parsing from URL in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, parsing, xmlpullparser

I am trying to parse some specific data from an online xml (mysite.com/data.xml) that is refreshing every some time. How I can do this? I tried other examples on internet but it doesn't worked for me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

[android](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml)

```
private List readFeed(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    List entries = new ArrayList();

    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "feed");
    while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
        if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            continue;
        }
        String name = parser.getName();
        // Starts by looking for the entry tag
        if (name.equals("entry")) {
            entries.add(readEntry(parser));
        } else {
            skip(parser);
        }
    }
    return entries;
}
```

Comment: I know how to parse from a local xml file in android studio, i done it, but I don't know how I can do this from an online xml file. How I can take data from there and display it? All examples that I try did not work for me.

Comment: can you put the xml file?

Comment: Xml is like this... and I want to display **Artist Name** and **Song Title**

`<Schedule System="System">
<Event status="happening" startTime="11:14:32" eventType="song">
<Announcement Display="Now On Air:"/>
<Song title="Song Title">
<Artist name="Artist Name" URL=""/>
<System ID="19089"/>
<PlayLister ID=""/>
<Media runTime="04:24"/>
<Expire Time="11:18:56"/>
<SongURL/>
<SongBarCode/>
<SongCDKey/>
</Song>
</Event>
</Schedule>`